# Can Xvfb be enabled in Jenkins declarative pipeline in order to execute Selenium headless tests

Tags: selenium, jenkins-pipeline, xvfb

Trying to enable Xvfb in Jenkins declarative pipeline to be able to run Selenium headless tests from the pipeline definition.

Have been able to run Selenium tests in a standard Jenkins (Linux) job. That's fine, i.e. Xvfb can be enabled under build (after plugin install) in the Jenkins job and then can Python virtual env be setup and Selenium tests executed from shell.

But I want to have a pipeline scope/setup. But in pipeline type jobs the Xvfb doesn't show up. And I haven't been able to find an answer if and how it can be enabled from the declarative pipeline code itself. Is it possible?

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, every job which is pipeline have a link on left side of job page "Pipeline Syntax" when you go there it will help you a lot for some non obvious cases. So, for your case: [image: check this out]

Comment: Thanks,

Did a work around for this. But hope that I can try it out.

Comment: but first should install the xvfb plugin in jenkins?  or without install could be use it?

Comment: you need to install plugin first